# Generating packing slips depending on product type

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

My abstract class. Product will have multiple child classes those will be different types of Product

```
 public abstract class Product
            {
                private int productId;
                public int ProductId
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return productId;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        productId = value;
                    }
                }
        
                private double cost;
                public double Cost
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return cost;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        cost = value;
                    }
                }
                protected IPayment payment;
                protected IEmail email;
                public string DoPayment()
                {
                    return payment.MakePayment();
                }
        
                public void setDifferentPaymentMethod(IPayment payment)
                {
                    this.payment = payment;
                }
            }
```

Concrete implementation of Product Class . How can I avoid instantiating PackingSlip here. Shall I create a factory?

```
 public class PhysicalProduct:Product
    {
        public PhysicalProduct()
        {
            payment = new PackingSlip();
        }
    }
```

Concrete implementation of Product Class

```
public class BookProduct:PhysicalProduct
    {
        public BookProduct():base()
        {
            payment = new DuplicatePackingSlip();           
        }
    }
```

Strategy class

```
 internal class DuplicatePackingSlip : IPayment
    {
        public string MakePayment()
        {
            return "Generating Duplicate Packing SLip for Royalty Department";
        }
    }
```

Strategy.

```
 internal class PackingSlip : IPayment
        {
            public string MakePayment()
            {
                return "Generating Packing Slip";
            }
        }
```

Is this the right way to implement if we want to have open/closed principle?

Answer (score 2):

### Indentation

Yours is highly inconsistent. It's best to use an autoformatter to ensure that this remains sane and consistent.

### Property boilerplate

This:

```
            private int productId;
            public int ProductId
            {
                get
                {
                    return productId;
                }
                set
                {
                    productId = value;
                }
            }
```

is both very Java and unnecessary given the syntactic sugar that C# has supported for several years:

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

### Factory?

> How can I avoid instantiating PackingSlip here

Why do you want to avoid instantiating it? Is it because `PhysicalProduct` is supposed to be an abstract class as well? If so, you are correct to want to avoid assigning an instance in the abstract class, since your assignment in the `BookProduct` constructor will overwrite this value.

There are several approaches you can follow. One is to make the top-level constructor accept an instance of `IPayment`, and to pass a new instance via `base()`.

Another approach is to make the abstract base class a generic, where the generic type is forced to implement `IPayment`. The abstract class would not need to accept a new instance, and would be able to construct its own instance so long as the [new constraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) is imposed.

### Redundant base call

This:

```
    public BookProduct():base()
```

should not need to explicitly call `base`.

### MakePayment

One of two things has happened here. Either you've omitted a bunch of code, which would technically make this section of the question off-topic; or `MakePayment` is both misnamed and mischaracterized as a function. If the latter, make it a get-only property and rename it to something like `Description`.